# Post Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application which has to sync clients data to server. I would like to post the data using a Map with one key and multiple data to store the columns (for example the name column will be like: key='name', value='John', 'Bill', 'Linda', etc.). Is it possible to post data in this format?
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you can post data even using List<String> coz you know that name key will be alway there

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

you can do it, 
this can be helpful for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(
            "car         toyota\n" +
            "car         bmw\n" +
            "car         honda\n" +
            "fruit       apple\n" +
            "fruit       banana\n" +
            "computer    acer\n" +
            "computer    asus\n" +
            "computer    ibm");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        String key = s.next();
        if (!map.containsKey(key))
            map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());

        map.get(key).add(s.next());
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I have the Map generated but I do not know which method to use to post it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("John");
        list.add("Bill");
        list.add("Linda");
        map.put("name",list);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> item:map.entrySet()){
            List<String> newList = map.get(item.getKey());
        }
```